# How to prevent a function from being cast to bool

Tags: python

The following python code has a bug:

```
class Location(object):
    def is_nighttime():
        return ...

if location.is_nighttime:
    close_shades()
```

The bug is that the programmer forgot to call `is_nighttime` (or forgot to use a `@property` decorator on the method), so the method is <strike>cast by `bool`</strike> evaluated as `True` without being called.

Is there a way to prevent the programmer from doing this, both in the case above, and in the case where `is_nighttime` is a standalone function instead of a method? For example, something in the following spirit?

```
is_nighttime.__bool__ = TypeError
```

Comment: You forgot the `()` to call the function. Function objects themselves are always truthy.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `if is_nighttime():`? Or do you want to somehow prevent this unintended type-cast?

Comment: Nope. If you want to catch this, run a linter. Similarly, you're not going to be able to prevent accidentally putting a function in a list, or accidentally printing a function to stdout.

Comment: Uh, guys? I think the questioner knows he needs to call the function. The question is about catching the bug, not fixing it.

Comment: Python does not do *any* casting, that's not a thing in this language. `if` [tests the truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of whatever you pass in, and function objects are no exception.

Answer (score 10):

In theory, you could wrap the function in a function-like object with a `__call__` that delegates to the function and a `__bool__` that raises a TypeError. It'd be really unwieldy and would probably cause more bad interactions than it'd catch - for example, these objects won't work as methods unless you add more special handling for that - but you could do it:

```
class NonBooleanFunction(object):
    """A function wrapper that prevents a function from being interpreted as a boolean."""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __bool__(self):
        raise TypeError
    __nonzero__ = __bool__

@NonBooleanFunction
def is_nighttime():
    return True  # We're at the Sun-Earth L2 point or something.

if is_nighttime:
    # TypeError!
```

There's still a lot of stuff you can't catch:

```
nighttime_list.append(is_nighttime)  # No TypeError ._.
```

And you have to remember to explicitly apply this to any functions you don't want being treated as booleans. You also can't do much about functions and methods you don't control; for example, you can't apply this to `str.islower` to catch things like `if some_string.islower:`.

If you want to catch things like this, I recommend using static analysis tools instead. I think IDEs like PyCharm might warn you, and there should be linting tools that can catch this.

---

If you want these things to work as methods, here's the extra handling for that:

```
import functools

class NonBooleanFunction(object):
    ...  # other methods omitted for brevity
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return NonBooleanFunction(functools.partial(self.func, instance))
```

Answer (score 8):

This is something you can approach with *static code analysis.*

For instance, [`pylint`](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/index.html) has a [related warning](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/features.html):

> `using-constant-test (W0125):`
>
> Using a conditional statement with a
>   constant value Emitted when a conditional statement (If or ternary if)
>   uses a constant value for its test. This might not be what the user
>   intended to do.

Demo:

If `is_nightmare` is not called:

```
$ pylint test.py
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
W:  4, 0: Using a conditional statement with a constant value (using-constant-test)
```

If called:

```
$ pylint test.py
************* Module test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
```

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: `if is_nighttime():`, with parenthesis to call it.

Longer answer:

`is_nighttime` points to a function, which is a non-None type.  `if` looks for a condition which is a boolean, and casts the symbol `is_nighttime` to boolean.  As it is not zero and not None, it is True.

Comment: Snicker.   I wonder how often this cycle of "answer question -> change question -> downvote answer" can be followed?