# Prevent implicit casts

Tags: python, mypy

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335027/how-to-prevent-a-function-from-being-cast-to-bool), is there anyway in Mypy to prevent implicit casts?  For example, casts to bool:

```py
x = (0, 0)

def is_good() -> bool:
    return False

if x and is_good:  # I'd like Mypy to report 2 errors here
    print('this will be printed')
```

Comment: There is not implicit cast here, really.

Comment: There are no implicit casts here. The operands of `and` don't have to be boolean.

Comment: The logical operators test whether the values are "truthy", not whether they're `True` or `False`.

Comment: you can see this if you do `print ((0, 0) and (1, 1))`

Comment: So, short answer, no, there isn't, because that would go against the Python data model.

Comment: This is more of a linter job than a type checker job. There are no type problems here.